# Using case statements to chop up a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a table stored in postgres which looks like this:

```
Column    RowIdx    Value
1         0         Dr A
1         1         Mr B
1         2         Mrs C
2         0         101
2         1         105
2         2         127
3         0         Red
3         1         Green
3         2         Blue
4         0         Miss D
4         1         Mr E
4         2         Ms F
5         0         23
5         1         197
5         2         256
6         0         Black
6         1         Brown
6         2         Yellow
```

When I want to extract a table that looks like this:

```
Name    HumanID    FavouriteColor
Dr A    101        Red
Mr B    105        Green
Mrs C   127        Blue
```

I use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN Column=1 THEN Value ELSE null END) AS Name,
    max(CASE WHEN Column=2 THEN Value ELSE null END) AS HumanID,
    max(CASE WHEN Column=3 THEN Value ELSE null END) AS FavouriteColor

WHERE (Column=1 OR Column=2 OR Column=3) 

GROUP BY RowIdx 
ORDER BY RowIdx
```

This works perfectly fine.  I now want to export a table that looks like this:

```
Name    HumanID    FavouriteColor
Dr A    101        Red
Mr B    105        Green
Mrs C   127        Blue
Miss D  23         Black
Mr E    197        Brown
Mrs C   256        Yellow
```

I modified my SQL statement to this:

```
SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN (Column=1 OR Column=4) THEN Value ELSE null END) AS Name,
    max(CASE WHEN (Column=2 OR Column=5) THEN Value ELSE null END) AS HumanID,
    max(CASE WHEN (Column=3 OR Column=6) THEN Value ELSE null END) AS FavouriteColor

WHERE (Column=1 OR Column=2 OR Column=3 OR Column=4 OR Column=5 OR Column=6) 

GROUP BY RowIdx 
ORDER BY RowIdx
```

However this doesn't seem to work, I'm just getting the first table again.  I know enough sql to get by, but I don't really understand what order the statements are being evaluated in, which is making it hard to figure out why I'm getting the result that I am.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT: Just to give some more context.  My system holds hundreds of thousands of csv files.  It does this by 'stacking' the columns of a csv file into a single column, then inserting it into the table.  I can guarantee that ordering of columns/cells that come from the same csv file, but I cannot guarantee it between csv files.  The example I gave above represents two csv files that have been imported.  Each file contains information about a person.  The operation I'm trying to implement would allow my to merge the two csv files.

I can achieve the result by exporting one table, then exporting the other, and then copying the right bits together.  I'd like to do it through this SQL statement since I think it's more efficient (due to other constraints within the system).

Comment: Your schema doesn't make much sense. It seems like [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model), but it's not. You use columns 1-4, 2-5, 3-6 for the same purpose, while rows (identified by `RowIdx`?) are mingled. I think you need to fix your schema first (probably with dropping EAV).

Comment: The schema does make sense, it just has a fairly length reason for being that way.  This is a very cut down example of how it works, but it illustrates the problem.  My tool stores hundreds of thousands of csv files.  It does this by 'stacking' the columns of csv files into a single column and inserting them into a table like this.  Column 1-4, 2-5, and 3-6 represent data from different csv files which have the same meaning (name, id, color), and I want to (non permentantly) merge them together.

Comment: then (at least) you should indicate which row comes from which source. Without this information, this task cannot be done reliably (f.ex. within a `CsvFormat` field, then you could `GROUP BY CsvFormat, RowIdx`) -- so again, fix your schema, or please include all your columns in your example (if some just left out for the sake of simplicity).

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing?  'Column' is the id of the column the data came from, RowIdx is the row index?

Comment: yes, but you mix `RowIdx` from different sources. That's why all the solutions below contains hacky math magic, like `ceil(col::float / 3)` or `Column % 3` -- it *can* be done, but only if you can guarantee that `Column` is unique between sources, or you can come up with a formula, which can calculate the source. But this table design will be always painful to query, unless you change it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'll have more of a think on it.  I can guarantee that column is unique (there is a secondary table which contains all the metadata about the columns and where they came from.  It is painful to query, but changing the schema isn't really an option since everything is built around it and there are all sorts of other constraints involved.  I'm going to post an answer which breaks the query down into multiple selects, but I don't think it's the most optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to define each group/set

where 3 needs to be changed to the number of rows in each set of data.

```
SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN col%3=1 THEN Value END) AS Name,
    max(CASE WHEN col%3=2 THEN Value END) AS HumanID,
    max(CASE WHEN col%3=0 THEN Value END) AS FavouriteColor,
    round((col-1)/3,0) as set
FROM FOO
GROUP BY round((col-1)/3,0), rowidx
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/20e22/13/0

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT max(CASE WHEN RowIdx = 1 THEN Value END) AS Name,
       max(CASE WHEN RowIdx = 2 THEN Value END) AS HumanID,
       max(CASE WHEN RowIdx = 3 THEN Value END) AS FavouriteColor
WHERE RowIdx in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY column;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This is not possible since I have no guarantee that the data will be regularly spaced like this.  I'll update my question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dynamically generating an artificial unique identifier for each "human" that partitions columns 1-3 from columns 4-6 (modified from my original version to eliminate the subquery):

```
-- Edited so that "like" column numbers are now enumerated instead of modulo-computed
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (1, 4) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (2, 5) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS HumanID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (3, 6) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS FavouriteColor
FROM foo  -- Just my name for your table
GROUP BY (ceil(col::FLOAT / 3), rowidx)
ORDER BY (ceil(col::FLOAT / 3), rowidx);
```

Using your data:

```
postgres=# select * from foo;
 col | rowidx | value
-----+--------+--------
   1 |      0 | Dr A
   1 |      1 | Mr B
   1 |      2 | Mrs C
   2 |      0 | 101
   2 |      1 | 105
   2 |      2 | 127
   3 |      0 | Red
   3 |      1 | Green
   3 |      2 | Blue
   4 |      0 | Miss D
   4 |      1 | Mr E
   4 |      2 | Ms F
   5 |      0 | 23
   5 |      1 | 197
   5 |      2 | 256
   6 |      0 | Black
   6 |      1 | Brown
   6 |      2 | Yellow
(18 rows)

postgres=# SELECT
postgres-#   MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (1, 4) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS Name,
postgres-#   MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (2, 5) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS HumanID,
postgres-#   MAX(CASE WHEN col IN (3, 6) THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS FavouriteColor
postgres-# FROM foo  -- Just my name for your table
postgres-# GROUP BY (ceil(col::FLOAT / 3), rowidx)
postgres-# ORDER BY (ceil(col::FLOAT / 3), rowidx);
  name  | humanid | favouritecolor
--------+---------+----------------
 Dr A   | 101     | Red
 Mr B   | 105     | Green
 Mrs C  | 127     | Blue
 Miss D | 23      | Black
 Mr E   | 197     | Brown
 Ms F   | 256     | Yellow
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I think my example was bad.  I cannot guarantee that columns of a similar type are input with regularly (i.e. I don't know that every 1st column is a name, 2nd is an id, and 3rd is a color).  I know the id's of the columns I want to export together.

Comment: @Andy Understood, changed the query so that the columns corresponding to the same attribute are now explicitly enumerated as an array.  Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with the following solution:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "tempTable";
CREATE TEMP TABLE "tempTable" (name text, humanid text, color text);

-- Insert first csv table
INSERT INTO "tempTable" (SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=1 THEN val ELSE null END) AS Name,
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=2 THEN val ELSE null END) AS HumanID,
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=3 THEN val ELSE null END) AS FavouriteColor

FROM sample
WHERE (columnid=1 OR columnid=2 OR columnid=3) 

GROUP BY rowidx 
ORDER BY rowidx);

-- Insert second csv table
INSERT INTO "tempTable" (SELECT 
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=4 THEN val ELSE null END) AS Name,
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=5 THEN val ELSE null END) AS HumanID,
    max(CASE WHEN columnid=6 THEN val ELSE null END) AS FavouriteColor

FROM sample
WHERE (columnid=4 OR columnid=5 OR columnid=6) 

GROUP BY rowidx 
ORDER BY rowidx);


SELECT * FROM "tempTable";
```

This behaves as expected, but I expect it's not the most optimal solution.